# animation of vertical bars using processing

Tags: animation, automation, processing

I am basically trying to make a animation of vertical bars across the screen which should be equally spaced and continue until some key is pressed etc.. in the processing.org tool for animation.
I was able to get a kind of animation, but with hard coded values and had to write the same code again and again to generate the animation of bars for the whole frame/screen. I need to make it generic, so that changing the screen width or the size of the bars would not make me change the whole code but just the variables which control the parameters. Below is my code. I have written the code for three vertical bars but that needs to be done for the whole screen..

```java
int a;
int i;
int j;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  a = width/2;
  i = 0;

}

void draw() {
  background(51);

  //need to avoid these repetitions each time for each bar

  rect(a , 0, 25, width);  
  a = a - 1;
  if (a < 0) { 
   a = width; 
  }

  rect(i= a+50, 0, 25, width);  
  i = i - 1;
  if (i < 0) { 
   i = width + a; 
  }


  rect(j = i + 50, 0, 25, width);  
  j = j - 1;
  if (a < 0) { 
   j = width + i; 
  }

}
```

Comment: If you made your code sample self contained such that people could cut N paste it to execute people tend to offer more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an **array**.

An array is like a variable, only it can hold multiple values in its **indexes**. You can then use a **for loop** to iterate over the array and do stuff based on the values in the array.

Here's an example that uses an array to keep track of the line positions:

```java
float[] linePositions = new float[10];
float lineWidth = 25;
float lineSpacing = 25;
float lineSpeed = 1;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);

  for (int i = 0; i < linePositions.length; i++) {
    linePositions[i] = width/2 + (lineWidth+lineSpacing)*i;
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(51);

  //loop through the lines
  for (int i = 0; i < linePositions.length; i++) {

    //draw the line
    rect(linePositions[i], 0, lineWidth, width); 

    //move the line
    linePositions[i] -= lineSpeed;

    //wrap the line
    if ( linePositions[i] < 0) { 
      linePositions[i] = width;
    }
  }
}
```

More info on arrays can be found in [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/Array.html).

Comment: Hi!! this is kind of what I want and thanks a lot. But how do I know, how many lines array i would need for a given screen. Also, if I change the linewidth and the space between the bars the bars/lines should fill the whole screen accordingly. Also, when the bars leave the screen they just leave abruptly. they should instead leave gradually. I tried modifying parts of the code you provided but was unable to make these changes. Also, float variable array can take max of 100 elements which might be a problem if the thickness of the bars is very less. It should fill screen with changing bar width

Comment: @jenns That's a lot of questions. You might be better off just trying something out and posting your updated code in a new question. But basically, you'll have to do some basic math to figure out how many lines you want. Try drawing a picture with a piece of paper and a pencil to recognize the pattern. The bars leave the screen because you move them when their left side goes off the screen. Try to only move them when their right side goes off the screen. A float array can have many more elements than 100. If you want to change the width, then you might want to create a `Line` object.